# Preventing users of my web application from modifying image id while uploading to cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-upload, cloudinary

I am building a rails web application where users can upload images from the browser to cloudinary. I am thinking a bit ahead, and want to prevent users from playing with the parameters being passed, in order not to have undesirable output in may pages (empty images).

In my view I have the code for the cloudinary uploader:

```
<%= form_tag(some_path, :method => :post) do  %>
 <%= cl_image_upload_tag(:image_id) %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

Now, when the user upload the image it goes directly to cloudinary, and the process returns :image_id. When the user accepts the image, I receive it in my controller like this:

```
if params[:image_id].present?
  preloaded = Cloudinary::PreloadedFile.new(params[:image_id])         
  raise "Invalid upload signature" if !preloaded.valid?
 @model.image_id = preloaded.identifier
end
```

That image ID gets saved in my database for future retrieve.

Now what if the user uses a tool such as "curl", or any other method that would allow him to modify the returned :image_id before submitting it to the controller ? I will have a wrong value in my database that would be difficult to find and an empty image when I try to show it in my pages. What is the best method of avoiding this ?

Regards,

Comment: When your hypothetical mischievous user uses curl, are they submitting a request to your app or directly to cloudinary?  Would it be possible for them to submit directly to cloudinary?

Comment: Hello @MaxWilliams, in the end my user submits a request to my app, after uploading to cloudinary. I am not sure I can go around him submitting to my app, since he will need to accept the picture, in case he uploaded something else by mistake.

Comment: Give [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) a look.

Comment: Thanks @PatsyIssa for the link. The idea of storing a random token both in the session and the request and compare them is indeed interesting. I will give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `cl_image_upload_tag`, the value of `params[:image_id]` will contain a signature. The signature is validated by `PreloadedFile#valid?` You can know for sure that this `public_id` and `version` were returned by Cloudinary. If needed, you can also verify the version (unix timestamp) is reasonably recent.

Comment: Two thumbs up! I have to admit that I did not go through the documentation in details yet, and used the code as it is from cloudinary examples...